# Safari won't fit div to content, but Chrome did

Tags: css

For some reason, Safari won't fit the div to my content. I'm using a border to visualize the div, the main goal is to have border-bottom only, but I don't want it to stretch 100% the parent.

Chrome will fit the div to the length of `<p>`, whereas Safari stretched the div to 100% of the page width.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>OKAY</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

Comment: Try `#wrapper p { display: inline-block; }`.

Comment: Works OKAY on Safari 5.1.7 (as I thought it would) Also `width:auto;` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use box-sizing: border-box

```
#wrapper {
   display: inline-block;
   width: auto;
   border: 2px solid;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `#wrapper p {display: inline-block; }` That should do the trick.